# How to create MessageBox in Unity without event/delegate callback?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, messagebox

There is one part in MessageBox that I need to re-create in Unity.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(/*parameters*/);
//When code runs - appears MessageBox and next lines of code WAIT for result
//Only if button is pressed - code proceeds next lines.
if (result == DialogResult.Yes) { DoIt(); }
else { DoNotDoIt(); }
```

I've seen some realization with Action callbacks.
In that realization - MessageBox has Action fields and in MessageBox.Show() method you should add delegates to propriate Action's as parameters.
I can't use it in my case. I need to ensure that dialog result is set and only then continue to run code.

Comment: Should I use multithreading for this?

Comment: Id say no to multithreaded especially because you need it to stop. However. I would ask. Why cant you use a call back?  Personally id do this in a coroutine where you can wait until say messagebox.result!=null

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in Update. DialogResult could have 3 states, None, Yes and No. With None, you do nothing, Update returns and comes back next frame:

```
void Update()
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(/*parameters*/);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes) { DoIt(); }
    else if(result == DialogResult.No) { DoNotDoIt(); }
}
```

other way is coroutine which is basically same as update:

```
IEnumerator DialogSequence()
{         
     while(MessageBox.Show(/*parameters*/)== DialogResult.None) { yield return null;}
     DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(/*parameters*/);
     if (result == DialogResult.Yes) { DoIt(); }
     else if(result == DialogResult.No) { DoNotDoIt(); }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...
Maybe like this?

`private static DialogResult s_result;`

`private IEnumerator TryToDoStuff()`
`{`
`//some code`
`s_result = DialogResult.NONE;`
`yield return MessageBox.Show();`
`if (s_result == DialogResult.YES)`
`{`
`DoIt();`
`}`
`}`

Comment: How should I format code in comments? :(

Comment: You should add the MessageBox code.

Comment: You should not use `Update` or this ... you don't want to call `DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show` each and every frame! The Coroutine approach is better **but** currently it wait for only a single frame! You would want to do `while(result == DialogResult.None){ yield return null; }` and then you could use a `switch - case` for the rest ;)

Comment: The initial point was to avoid the callback (for unknown reasons), then the message box state has to be polled each frame. Else, you would never get the new state. The coroutine does have the issue that it should be in a while loop indeed.